# Am I letting the 'this' reference escape? (inner class in constructor instantiation, no event listener, no threads)

Tags: java

I am instantiating an inner class in my constructor but I'm not using it to start threads or as an event listener. For example:

```
public class Something {

    final InnerSomething innerSomething = new InnerSomething();

    public Something(Param arg) {
        super(arg);
    }

    private class InnerSomething {...}

    ...
}
```

EDIT: I copied & pasted the code from somewhere else and forgot to delete the "abstract" keyword.

EDIT2: "My" definition of "'this' reference escape" is the one found in the book Java Concurrency in Practice.

With the above code, am I allowing the 'this' reference to "escape"?

Comment: `this` refers to an *instance* of an object, abstract classes *cannot* be instantiated.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've removed the "abstract" keyword.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by letting the reference escape, and why that worries you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically you are since `InnerSomething` will have a reference to `this` *before* `Something`'s constructor returns.

However if you don't publish the reference and don't do anything with it in `InnerSomething`'s constructor, it should not create problems. Note that **it would be better to mark `innerSomething` private** as one could access `this` through the package-private field.

If you refer to JCiP #3.2.1, they state:

> More specifically, the `this` reference should not escape from the thread until after the constructor returns. The `this` reference can be stored somewhere by the constructor so long as it is not used by another thread until after construction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.  "Escape" means public access to a private reference that's mutable.  I don't see that in the code you've posted.

Do we agree on the meaning of the term?