# Object publication through passing an inner-class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

The question is not about concurrency.

I'm reading [B. Goetz's Java Concurrency in practice](https://github.com/HackathonHackers/programming-ebooks/blob/master/Java/Java%20Concurrency%20in%20Practice.pdf) and now I'm at the `section 3.2` about object publication. He said

> A final mechanism by which an object or its internal state can be
>   published is to publish ***an inner class instance***, as shown in
>   ThisEscape in Listing 3.7.

```
public class ThisEscape {
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
         source.registerListener(
              new EventListener() {
                  public void onEvent(Event e) {
                      doSomething(e);
                  }
              });
          }
     }
}
```

So, I tried to write my own harmful example of such publication. Here it is:

```
public class InnerPublication {

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        Subscriber s = new Subscriber();
        s.subscribe(new ToPublish(){ });
    }

    public abstract static class ToPublish{ }

    public static class Subscriber{
        public void subscribe(ToPublish tp){
            //How can I use the published enclosing instance to do some harm?
        }
    }
}
```

Since, [anonymous class is ***always (even in a static context)*** an inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5), we've got a publication here. But I don't see how I could use the publication to do some harm on the enclosing instance.

Comment: believe it or not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676796/how-does-this-reference-to-an-outer-class-escape-through-publishing-inner-clas seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @tharindu_DG Cool, thank you.

Comment: You cannot access the enclosing instance of the anonymous `ToPublish` subclass from the `Subscriber` member class (unless you use reflection). You need to do that from within your anonymous class itself.