# Safe construction in java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

This is in context of safe construction practice in java multi threading. I was reading through JCIP book, Can somebody explain me below line:

> an object is in a predictable, consistent state only after its
>   constructor  returns, so publishing an object from within its
>   constructor can publish an  incompletely constructed object. This is
>   true even if the publication is the  last statement in the
>   constructor.

Here I want to understand specific part '**This is true even if the publication is the
     last statement in the constructor**'

I understand it is not safe to start a thread from constructor, but is it also not safe when it is last statement in constructor?

My guess is about Why it is not safe is that, JVM could do reordering of statement and last statement would not be last anymore. Please comment on this or correct my understanding.

Edit: In question what I mean by starting a thread is that leaking `this` reference. And this leaking could happen by multiple means like publishing an event or start of a thread.

Comment: It is not safe if you leak a premature object, i.e. you call a method of another object in your constructor with `this` as parameter. The called method has already access to the passed reference, but the referenced object may not yet been fully constructed.

Comment: I understood this part, my question is what if it is last statement. Is my reasoning correct in question?

Comment: Maybe you're constructing an object that derives from the class you're currently in. In that case, the final object has not been fully constructed, not even after the last statement within the constructor.

Comment: The quote you're reading is talking about inner classes. It does not apply to the example you gave. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676796/how-does-this-reference-to-an-outer-class-escape-through-publishing-inner-clas

Comment: Here's a relevant bit from JSR 133 "A new guarantee of initialization safety should be provided. If an object is properly constructed (which means that references to it do not escape during construction), then all threads which see a reference to that object will also see the values for its final fields that were set in the constructor, without the need for synchronization.". 'properly constructed' is a key basis of the guarantees provided. No complete construction, no guarantees. Don't need to think deeply about reordering to explain this - model just says 'all bets are off, don't do this'.

Comment: I found few examples which clearly explains when it is not last statement. But I could not find anything if it is last statement. Otherwise I totally agree we should not escape reference while construction.

Comment: Maybe we should ask the author – @BrianGoetz

Comment: @MCEmperor Note that @-ing someone on StackOverflow only works if that person already participates in the question.

Comment: @yshavit Is it? Well, now think about it – that's a good thing, or else it would be a mess of user references everywhere ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are two insights that may help you here. First, a constructor is (mostly) just like any other method, for purposes of synchronization; namely, it doesn't inherently provide any (except as noted below). And secondly, thread safety is always between individual actions.

So let's say you have the following constructor:

```
MyClass() {
    this.i = 123;
    MyClass.someStaticInstance = this; // publish the object
}

// and then somewhere else:
int value = MyClass.someStaticInstance.i;
```

The question is: what can that last expression do?

- It can throw an NullPointerException, if `someStaticInstance` hasn't been set yet.
- It can also result in `value == 123`
- But interestingly, it can *also* result in `value == 0`

The reason for that last bit is that the actions can be reordered, and a constructor isn't special in that regard. Let's take a closer look at the actions involved:

- A. allocating the space for the new instance, and setting all its fields to their default values (0 for the `int i`)
- B. setting `<instance>.i = 123`
- C. setting `someStaticInstance = <instance>`
- D. reading `someStaticInstance`, and then its `i`

If you reorder those a bit, you can get:

- A. allocating the space for the new instance, and setting all its fields to their default values (0 for the `int i`)
- C. setting `someStaticInstance = <instance>`
- D. reading `someStaticInstance`, and then its `i`
- B. setting `<instance>.i = 123`

And there you have it -- `value` is 0, instead of 123.

JCIP is also warning you that leaks can happen in subtle ways. For instance, let's say you don't explicitly set that `someStaticInstance` field, but instead merely call `someListener.register(this)`. You've still leaked the reference, and you should assume that the listener you're registering with might do something dangerous with it, like assigning it to `someStaticInstance`.

This is true even if that `i` field is final. You get some thread safety from final fields, but only if you don't leak `this` from the constructor. Specifically, in [JLS 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5), it says:

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

The only way to guarantee the "only see a reference to an object after that object has completely initialized" is to not leak the reference from its constructor. Otherwise, you could imagine a thread reading `MyClass.someStaticInstance` in the moment just after the field was set, but before the JVM recognizes the constructor as finished.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is the last call in your constructor, it can lead to messy situations when you take inheritance into consideration. Here is some sample code to demonstrate the behaviour.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        A a = new B();

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": " + a);
    }

    public static void doSomethingWithA(final A a) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": " + a);
        });

        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class A {

    public A() {
        Test.doSomethingWithA(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        if (false) {
            System.out.println(MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    boolean isConstructed = false;

    public B() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.isConstructed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (  "B is " + (!this.isConstructed ? "not yet " : "")
                + "fully constructed.");
    }
}
```

Now, imagine `A` and `B` were developed by two different developers. Even though the developer of `A` leaked the premature object as the last statement in the constructor of `A`, it is not the last statement in the constructor of `B` (remember the implicit `super()` at the start of every constructor). Thus, the thread started in `doSomethingWithA(...)` gets access to a premature object. This is the reason why you should only call `final` methods of your own class in constructors. For further information, I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404369/4216641).

The design of `class A` is inherently flawed due to the preemptive leakage of `this` in the constructor, see [@yshavit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171603/4216641) for more details.

Comment: The issue discussed in JCIP is that the memory model doesn't make the same guarantees about what a thread will see in a partially constructed object. For instance, you can set a final field then leak out `this` and a different thread reading that field is not guaranteed to read the value you set.

Comment: @pvg I've just looked at the section in JCIP, and I don't think it's referring to final field semantics specifically. It's just issuing a blanket statement warning against publishing `this` from the constructor -- it doesn't get into the subtleties of why it's problematic even if the fields are final.

Comment: @yshavit hence 'for instance'. All the JMM guarantees apply to fully constructed objects. You don't need to make up inheritance cases to explain why 'last statement' is there.

Comment: I never said that this is the only case where this could happen. It is a case that can be explained with a reasonably code base.

Answer (score -1):

As an example

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        publish();
    }
    void publish() {
        System.out.println((consistent() ? "" : "in") + "consistent object");
    }
    protected boolean consistent() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Child extends MyClass {
    int result;
    public Child() {
        super();
        result = 42;
    }
    protected boolean consistent() {
        return result == 42;
    }
}
```