# how does inner class make this reference escape

Tags: java, concurrency

the noncompliant code example ["inner class" section](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/TSM01-J.+Do+not+let+the+this+reference+escape+during+object+construction#TSM01-J.Donotletthethisreferenceescapeduringobjectconstruction-NoncompliantCodeExample(InnerClass))

it seems that there no instance method is called in the inner class, so I don't know how this reference escaped in this snippet.

I've readed some problems, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045622/am-i-letting-the-this-reference-escape-inner-class-in-constructor-instantiat), but it is different

```java
public class DefaultExceptionReporter implements ExceptionReporter {
  public DefaultExceptionReporter(ExceptionReporter er) {
    er.setExceptionReporter(new ExceptionReporter() {
        public void report(Throwable t) {
          // report exception
        }
        public void setExceptionReporter(ExceptionReporter er) {
          // register ExceptionReporter
        }
    });
  }
  // Default implementations of setExceptionReporter() and report()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of `DefaultExceptionReporter`, you instantiate an anonymous class. The anonymous class gets a reference to its parent class before the parent class is fully instantiated.

If the parent object had state, it would mean that the anonymous class could theoretically operate on it before it was fully constructed.

Hopefully this demonstrates the potential issue:

```
class DefaultExceptionReporter implements ExceptionReporter {

    private final int foo;

    public DefaultExceptionReporter(ExceptionReporter er) {
        er.setExceptionReporter(new ExceptionReporter() {

            {
                System.out.println(DefaultExceptionReporter.this.foo);
            }

            public void report(Throwable t) {}
            public void setExceptionReporter(ExceptionReporter er) {}
        });
        foo = 1;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This will print zero, even though `foo` is final and assigned 1. A final variable has ended up having two values which should never normally be possible.

Because your object is stateless, I don't think it's a big deal. You should probably declare the class as `final` though, so it's not possible to extend it and add state.

Comment: so, it's mean that weather the outer class instance `this` reference escape or not, determined by the implementation of inner class. And it just same with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678279/4916832)? At first I just focus on the intention of the inner class code.  It's just a empty implementation or a  placeholder for default exception reporter. so if I use this snippet in practice, the empty inner class itself could not make this reference escape, right?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when `DefaultExceptionReporter` publishes the anonymous class, it implicitly publishes the enclosing `DefaultExceptionReporter` instance as well. You can check this by writing a simple program to actually access that instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExceptionReporter rep = new DefaultExceptionReporter(new ExceptionReporter() {
        @Override
        public void setExceptionReporter(ExceptionReporter er) {
            for (Field field : er.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                System.out.println(field);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void report() { }
    });
}
```

**Output:**

```
final my.package.DefaultExceptionReporter my.package.DefaultExceptionReporter$1.this$0
```

This is because an anonymous class is always a non-static inner class ([see reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)) and these kinds of classes always have an implicit `this` reference to the enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

Technically in this example you let `this` reference escape.

Let's imagine that :

- some other thread has access to the `ExceptionReporter` instance that is passed to the constructor of `DefaultExceptionReporter`
- you actually access the outer instance through `DefaultExceptionReporter.this` in methods' of your anonymous class instance (for example you want to access field or invoke a method)

In this case other thread might invoke methods on the `ExceptionReporter` passed to the constructor of `DefaultExceptionReporter`. And if those methods invoke methods from the instance that is set through `setExceptionReporter` - other thread can potentially access 
`DefaultExceptionReporter` before it's instance is fully created. The access from other `Thread` could be done through chain of references :

`ExceptionReporter`(passed to the constructor) -> `ExceptionReporter`(anonymous) -> `DefaultExceptionReporter.this`.